# Appium + Python on Android - scrolling doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, appium

Appium + Python on Android - scrolling
I have an app to automate tests for. Scenario looks like this:

I tap on date picker > calendar appears

I tap on the year > a list of years appears

I want to scroll until '1993' is visible

the year '1993' is not visible on the screen and I want to keep scrolling until it is. I've tried

```
TouchAction(driver).press(x=746, y=1351).move_to(x=755, y=588).release().perform()
```

^but I don't want to use coordinates, plus I'd have to repeat that line several times.

```
def set_year(self):
visibility = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//android.widget.TextView[@text='1993']").is_displayed()
while not visibility:
TouchAction(self.driver).press(x=746, y=1351).move_to(x=755, y=588).release().perform()
visibility = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//android.widget.TextView[@text='1993']").is_displayed()
else:
print("not found")
```

^but it keeps throwing me selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters error, since as I said, it's not visible

What is the best approach for this?

```
el = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(<your_xpath>) driver.execute_script("mobile: scrollTo", {"element": el.id})
```

^this one gives me an error saying that a tuple does not have id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appium will throw an error each time an element is not find.
So, your script stops before swiping, when you define your variable visibility.

Try this :

```
def set_year(self):
    visibility = False
    i = 0

    while not visibility or i<100:
        i += 1
        try:
            visibility = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 
                "//android.widget.TextView[@text='1993']").is_displayed()
        except:
            TouchAction(self.driver).press(x=746, y=1351).move_to(x=755, 
                                           y=588).release().perform()
    if not visibility:
        print("not found")
```

Your script will scroll down until the year 1993 is found.